# how to get cursor position in soft keyboard in landscape

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ontouchlistener

How to get cursor position in soft keyboard in landscape. In portrait mode I can use OnTouchListener but in landscape mode, the OnTouchListener does not work on full screen soft keyboard.

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            cursorPosition = editText.getOffsetForPosition(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY()); // will give you the position of the nearest chracter.
            return false;
      }
});
```

In short, how can I do what above does on landscape full screen keyboard..

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `OnTouchListener`  will not work in fullscreen mode of EditText. However, if it is helpful for you, you can use a listener which is called when a cursor position is changed. To do that, extend `EditText` and override its `onSelectionChanged` method:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText
{
    public CustomEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd)
    {
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
       // here you get cursor position change
    }
}
```

Comment: `onSelectionChanged` is used when SelectionSpan is applied to the character sequence but I want the position where user has touched. This is why I am using `OnTouchListener` in the first place.